# i hava 1 error when i do web login by asp.net

Tags: asp.net

my ideas: i select id(max) in table users to write table Userlogin. I get error:

> 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.'

```
   SELECT idUser 
   FROM Users 
   WHERE idUser = (SELECT MAX(idUser) FROM Users)
```

how to fix error? thank you.
img error: [Mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STeX2.png), [Myerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1LKb.png)

mycode:

```
  `` `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    namespace Web_tintuc2
    {
        public partial class DangKi : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private string connectString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-
```

RT3QMVS; Initial Catalog =web_tintuc; Integrated Security=True;";
SqlConnection sql_connect;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
            }
    
            protected void btn_thoat_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Trangchu.aspx");
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
            }
    
            protected void btn_dangki_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
            {
                sql_connect = new SqlConnection(connectString);
                sql_connect.Open();
                string username = txt_username.Text;
                string phone = txt_Phone.Text;
                string password = txt_password.Text;
                string name = txt_name.Text;
                string ngaysinh = txt_brithday.Text;
    
                string diachi = txt_diachi.Text;
                string email = txt_Email.Text;    
                DateTime aDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                string ngaydangki = aDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // fomat kiểu ngày thánh trong sql server
                string active = "Actived";
                string IdGruop = "2";
                string gioitinh1 = "Nam";
                String gioitinh2 = "Nữ";
                string sql_check = "select Username from Userlogin 
where Username='" + username + "' ";
                SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand(sql_check, 
sql_connect);
                SqlDataReader read = sql1.ExecuteReader();
    
                if (read.Read() == true)
    
                    Lb_thongbao.Text = "Username đã tồn tại";
                read.Close();
    
                if (Radio_nam.Checked == true)
                {
    
    
                    string sql_insert_toUser = " insert into Users(HoTen,Diachi,Email,Dienthoai,gioitinh,ngaysinh,idGroup,ngaydangki,active ) values('" + name + "','" + diachi + "','" + diachi + "','" + email + "','" + phone + "','" + gioitinh1 + "','" + ngaysinh + "','" + IdGruop + "','" + ngaydangki + "','" + active + "')";
                    SqlCommand sqlcommand1 = new 
SqlCommand(sql_insert_toUser, sql_connect);
                    sqlcommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string sql_id_users = "Select top 1 idUser from 
Users  order by idUser desc";
                    string sql_insert_to_UserLogin = "insert into 
Userlogin(Username,Password,idUser) values('" + username + "','" + 
password + "','" + sql_id_users + "') ";
                     SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new 
SqlCommand(sql_insert_to_UserLogin, sql_connect);
                    sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
    
                else if (Radio_nu.Checked == true)
                {
    
    
                    string sql_insert_toUser = " insert into Users(HoTen,Diachi,Email,Dienthoai,gioitinh,ngaysinh,idGroup,ngaydangki,active )values('" + name + "','" + diachi + "','" + email + "','" + phone + "','" + gioitinh2 + "','" + ngaysinh + "','" + IdGruop + "','" + ngaydangki + "','" + active + "')";
                    SqlCommand sqlcommand1 = new SqlCommand(sql_insert_toUser, sql_connect);
                    sqlcommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string sql_id_users = "  SELECT idUser FROM Users 
WHERE idUser = (SELECT MAX(idUser) FROM Users) ";
                    string sql_insert_to_UserLogin = "insert into 
Userlogin(Username,Password,idUser) values('" + username + "','" + 
password + "','"+sql_id_users+"') ";
                  
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand_2 = new 
SqlCommand(sql_insert_to_UserLogin, sql_connect);
                    sqlCommand_2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }'' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from your `insert` statement (line 62). You have single quotes around the variable `sql_id_users`. Remove the single quotes. It's treating the value as `varchar` since you have it enclosed in single quotes but it expects an integer.

Suggestion: When you post, please post your code as text and not an image.

Comment: OKI, I  had test it, but it no active. "Suggestion: When you post, please post your code as text and not an image." i will edit it. thank you